# Executing commandline commands from Python using subprocess module

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to use the `subprocess module` in python and trying to fetch the `process id` of `firefox`

```
cmd = "firefox &" 
fire = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
fire_task_procs = find_task(fire.pid)
print "fire_task_procs",fire_task_procs
```

I think I am getting the `pid` of the commandline argument that I am executing.. am I doing something wrong?
I confirmed that it is not the same using the `ps aux | grep firefox`

Answer (score 2):

If you use `shell=True` the pid you'll get ist that of the started shell, not that of the process you want, specially as you use `&` to send the process into background.

You should use the long (list) form of supplying the parameters, without `&`, as that makes little sense anyway if you combine it with output redirection.

Comment: If I don't use `shell=True`, I get the following error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    fire = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: If you don't use `shell=True` and you pass the string `"firefox &"`, you will get an error, because that's not a reasonable arg string. (Depending on your platform, this may ask `firefox` to open a file called `&`, or it may try to find a program named `firefox &`, neither of which is right.) But if you just drop the `&`, it is. And ideally, switch to an arg list. (As the docs say a few times, "Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred" when you're not using `shell=True`, especially on POSIX.) So, change `cmd` to `["firefox"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the shell, instead just use

```
subprocess.Popen(['firefox'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

However, if firefox is already running then this will not work either since in this case firefox will use some IPC to tell the existing process to open a new window and then terminates.